# how to check if office document excel is readonly office.js addin

Tags: office-js

i want to know if  there is any API/function which can be used to detect if office document is read-only. I am creating an office add-in using office.js library. the document is shared to other user in readonly mode. if i use following property, it shows readWrite but actually document is in readonly mode. following property is not helping

```
var docMode = Office.context.document.mode; // did not work, it gives value of manifest file i guess
```

I am trying following thing, it worked but not sure if that is the right approach. if the file is in one drive it give url as http://d.doc.onedrive..something like this.

```
if (Office.context.document.url.indexOf("https://excel.officeapps.live.com") > -1) {// its in read-only mode-this is the unique folder name where the file is 
            $("#container").show();
            $("#readOnlyArea").show();
        } else {
            $("#mainArea").show();}
```

Comment: Let me follow up on that.  Could you try this out in both Excel desktop and online, and check what the return values of `Office.context.document.mode` are for both read-write and read-only documents?

Comment: that value doesnot work. it give the answer as readWrite (i think it gets that value from manifest) even if its not writable. i have tried that. btw i have sent you email about this on your gmail id..i will update that here.

Comment: OK, I'll ask someone on my team...

Comment: hi Michael, can you help me with this question also..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492972/is-it-possible-to-save-the-file-shared-by-office-one-organization-work-account-t?noredirect=1#comment64387157_38492972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a really good question. Since Excel has the very interesting scratch mode, basically even though Excel is in read only mode. Both users and add-ins are still able to write to the workbook. Therefore this API always returns ReadWrite meaning the add-in is able to write. The current behavior is by design. However, these changes can't be saved for read only files. We are aware this is a gap and we have added it to our backlog. Thanks for raising this issue.

Thanks,
Sky